# Does .NET interop cache the generated unmanaged thunks to managed method?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, pinvoke

For example, I use unmanaged Win32 timer:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void TimerProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr nIDEvent, uint dwTime);

[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetTimer(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIDEvent, 
    uint uElapse, TimerProc lpTimerFunc);

// ...

TimerProc timerProc = delegate { this.Beep(); };

// ...
var timerId = NativeMethods.SetTimer(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 500, timerProc);
```

I wonder if the unmanaged pointer for `lpTimerFunc` which is passed to the actual `SetTimer` API remains the same for as longs as the managed `timerProc` remians the same, no matter how many times I call `NativeMethods.SetTimer`? Or does a new unmanaged thunk get generated for `timerProc` each time I call `NativeMethods.SetTimer`?

Comment: There's one thunk for one delegate *type*.  It is reference counted by delegate objects, the thunk is released when the last delegate object is GCed.  Also the reason your code is wrong and will crash, timerProc cannot be a local variable unless you use GCHandle.Alloc() to keep the reference alive.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for clarifying it. In actual code `timerProc` is a member of the main form class which keeps it alive until `KillTimer`, so I don't need `GCHandle.Alloc()`.

Comment: @HansPassant, "one thunk for one delegate *type*." -did you mean for each delegate *instance*? The delegate type is `TimerProc` here, I could have many callback instances of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each delegate will have its own thunk, so it depends on how you create your delegate.  If you create a new delegate each time you call SetTimer, you'll have lots of them.  If create it once for your class, you'll only have one.